# Python not recognising.wav file

Tags: python, wav

I am attempting to read in a .wav file and plot the spectrogram using python. When I run the following code I get the error "[Errno 2]" No such file or directory: 'test.wav' ". The test.wav is saved in my working directory. Any ideas on what could be causing this?
**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy.io import wavfile


def main():
    sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read("test.wav")
    frequencies, times, spectrogram = signal.spectrogram(samples, sample_rate)
    plt.pcolormesh(times, frequencies, spectrogram)
    plt.imshow(spectrogram)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
    plt.show()

main()
```

Comment: Is `test.wav` is there in the directory from where you are executing the code ? If not use `samples = wavfile.read(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test.wav'))`

Comment: @kvmahesh yes - it is